# add mailto: before every email

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

hey so I have a html table with a bunch of people and email addresses. I want to add mailto: before every email. is there anyway to do this using javascript, or preferably a find/replace function in vscode?

```
  <tr>
    <td>Mrs. john doe</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>first.last4@example.com</td>
    <td>Principal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Mr. jerremy fields</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>first.last@example.com</td>
    <td>Deputy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Mrs. rebecca statin</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>first.last@example.com</td>
    <td>Deputy</td>
</tr>
```

ive tried using a vscode find/replace like this:

Find: `.+?..+?@example.com`
Replace:     `<td>mailto:.+?..+?@example.com`

The find works, yet when I try and replace the actual '.?' is being replaced instead of the previous wildcard expression

thanks in advance

Comment: can you share your javascript code as well?

Comment: With vscode. find pattern - <td>(.*?)@example.com. Replace pattern - <td>mailto:$1@example.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below. Remember - for mailto: to work, it needs to be in an `<a>`

Adding a CSS class to the `<td>` will make the code easier to maintain because if the table structure changes, the email addresses can still be accessed.

```
<td class="email">email@example.com</td>

const emails = document.querySelectorAll(".email");
```

```js
const emails = document.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-of-type(3)");
emails.forEach(e => e.innerHTML = '<a href="mailto:' + e.textContent + '">' + e.textContent + '</a>');
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Mrs. john doe</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>first.last4@example.com</td>
  <td>Principal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Mr. jerremy fields</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>first.last@example.com</td>
  <td>Deputy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Mrs. rebecca statin</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>first.last@example.com</td>
  <td>Deputy</td>
</tr>
</table>
```